# Angular 8 differential loading and generate only ES5 bundle

Tags: angular8

Noticing some serious time taken to build the library bundles. We have 3 library modules and an application in the angular.json and the overall time to build these has gone up. Is there a way to tweak the **browserslist** to turn off the differential loading and generate only es5 bundle? Is there a way to stay on the least common multiple ES5 that is supported everywhere and generate only that?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved at development environment change the option on `tsconfig.json`, found the property `target` and set `target: "es5"`. After this change, Angular CLI builds your code with ES5 bundle only.